Tinkercad multimeter doesn't work
Measuring voltage and current in Tinkercad, tell me why the voltage does not change when connected in series and the current in the circuit does not change when connected in parallel.



it's working exactly as expected, you're just using it wrong.

That seems exactly right. Why do you think it should be different?

Can you elaborate on why you think it should change?

In an electrical circuit, when connected in series, there must be the same current throughout the entire section of the circuit and the voltage is different. When connected in parallel, the current should be different in each branch and the voltage is the same.

Explain that maybe I'm doing something wrong in Tinkercad itself.

That’s KCL and KVL indeed, but how does your simulation violate that?

I don't understand it myself)

In the top example, you're shorting out the LEDs with two ammeters. The approximately 9mA (9V/1kΩ) flows half through one and half through the other.
Note: please learn to use an ammeter correctly before connecting it to a real circuit or you'll break things. Voltmeters are generally more forgiving.
In the second example there are 5 mathematically identical LED models in series. Very little current flows with such a low voltage per LED so the total adds up to almost 9V (and almost nothing across the 1kΩ resistor). The voltage splits evenly per LED.
